Correct next_req() to paginate an API request using httr2?
I want to iteratively call a paginated API using httr2's req_perform_iterative function, where the response provides a next url to request.
However, I cannot seem to correctly form the next_req() argument or use the iteration helpers, such as iterate_with_cursor(), and the examples in the documentation are light. In my case I need to use the next url rather than offset the page number as that is the pagination system of the API I am calling.
Could someone please help me form a correct next_req() function?
We can use the rick and morty api as an example:
library(httr2)

# request a single page
req <- request("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=1") |>
  req_perform() |>
  resp_body_json()

# return the url for the next page
next_url <- req$info$"next"

How do I turn this into a working req_perform_iterative() function that will return multiple pages? Thanks!

While you could use iterate_with_cursor() here, it would fit better if next in response body would be just a next page number.
For this particular example (complete URL for next page in response body) it's probably easier to just build a new iteration helper, we can take one of the existing ones as a template:
library(httr2)

# existing iteration helper, follows url found in the Link header:
iterate_with_link_url()
#> function (resp, req) 
#> {
#>     url <- resp_link_url(resp, rel)
#>     if (!is.null(url)) {
#>         req %>% req_url(url)
#>     }
#> }

# custom helper based on iterate_with_link_url(),
# follow next url from response body
iterate_with_body_info_next <- function(resp, req) {
  url <- resp_body_json(resp)$info$`next`
  if (!is.null(url)) {
    req %>% req_url(url)
  }
}

resps <- 
  request("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character") |> 
  req_perform_iterative(
    next_req = iterate_with_body_info_next,
    max_reqs = 3
)
resps
#> [[1]]
#> <httr2_response>
#> GET https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character
#> Status: 200 OK
#> Content-Type: application/json
#> Body: In memory (19496 bytes)
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> <httr2_response>
#> GET https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=2
#> Status: 200 OK
#> Content-Type: application/json
#> Body: In memory (10380 bytes)
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> <httr2_response>
#> GET https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=3
#> Status: 200 OK
#> Content-Type: application/json
#> Body: In memory (9723 bytes)

# info object from the 1st request body
str(resp_body_json(resps[[1]])$info)
#> List of 4
#>  $ count: int 826
#>  $ pages: int 42
#>  $ next : chr "https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character?page=2"
#>  $ prev : NULL


Though iterate_with_offset() would also work just fine, define url parameter that would be incremented and a function that extracts total number of pages from the first response and you should end up with something like this:
request("https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character") |> 
  req_perform_iterative(
    next_req = iterate_with_offset(
      param_name = "page",
      resp_pages = \(resp) resp_body_json(resp)$info$pages
    ),
    max_reqs = 3
  )

Created on 2024-10-18 with reprex v2.1.1
